# Rendering a server-side control using HTMLTextWriter makes control lose standard functionality (i.e. Click eventhandler)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2010, htmltextwriter

I want to add Server-Side controls (`CheckBoxList`s & `Button`):

`ChkBoxLst1` & `ChkBoxLst2` & `Button1` through Code-behind and then use an `HTMLTextWriter` to render the control.

I can't seem to be able to do this.

All of the above in a Visual WebPart.

What I have tried: 
Global:

```
CheckBoxList ChkBoxLst2 = new CheckBoxList();
Button Bttn2 = new Button();
Label lbl2 = new Label(); 

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
```

Page Load:

```
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            ChkBoxLst2.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
            ChkBoxLst2.Items.Add(new ListItem("Four", "4"));

            ChkBoxLst2.RenderControl(writer);
            lbl2.RenderControl(writer);
            Bttn2.Click += new EventHandler(this.Bttn2_Click);
            Bttn2.Text = "Click this HTMLText WriteButton!";
            Bttn2.RenderControl(writer); 

        }

        spn.InnerHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Event Handler:

```
 void Bttn2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ChkBoxLst2.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    lbl.Text += item.Text + ", ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The EventHandler does not get triggered and the selected values do not get saved the way I have done it above. Any ideas as to why not? I've tried a comparison of two checkbox lists, but the `HTMLTextWriter` implementation did not work whereas the simple .NET did of the same thing 
 all in all I think its my implementation of an HTMLTextWriter/how I add the server control.

Note that the spn is a literal span control in the markup.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried, and what problem you had?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have rendered these controls to the browser, the controls are not part of the control tree of the page, and will not even exist on postback. Any dynamically-added controls need to be added on every request.

Why play with HtmlTextWriter at all? Simply add the controls to the page during Page_Load, and they'll be rendered for you. Do so outside of the "if (!Page.IsPostBack)" and they'll be there every time the page loads, which is what you want.

Comment: thank you so much!! The behavior makes much much more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

try this method to render controls into an html string:

```
    public static string ControlRenderToString(Control tmpControl)
    {
        string Content;

        System.IO.StringWriter sWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htwObject = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
        tmpControl.RenderControl(htwObject);

        Content = sWriter.ToString();
        sWriter.Close();

        return Content;
    }
```

Comment: I think that is what I have, but I'm not sure maybe I'm overlooking something. I've edited the question with some code and detail.

Comment: @MyName, i don't think you can use you're click handler after rendering the control, try using javascript / ajax instead.

Comment: I'm calling the Click handler before rendering the control though, or does it get executed in a different sequence?